# Компиляция Java кода под Android в рантайме

Tags: android, компиляция, runtime

У меня есть строка названия класса и строка, содержащая код класса. Например, Example - название класса, а

```
public class Example {
    public void example() { System.out.println("Hello world!"); }
}
```

Соответственно, код класса

Я смотрел библиотеку Dexmaker, но так и не понял, можно ли с её помощью сгенерированный в строку код скомпилировать. И вот вопрос как раз в том, как сгенерированный в строку код скомпилировать для дальнейшего использования под Android?

Comment: А зачем вам это нужно? Что вы хотите этим достичь?

Comment: На дипломную работу создал ORM библиотеку с кодогенерацией и компиляцией моделей объектов и операций над ними. На обычных JVM всё работает, а вот под андроид Dalvik, поэтому обычный компилятор не подходит.

Comment: Обработай полученные классы в dx (входит в сдк)

Comment: Что ты имеешь ввиду?

Comment: Утилита dx предназначена для конвертации байткода из классов джавы в байткод дальвика (декс-файлы). Подробнее о компиляции: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/687556/ - пытаемся разобраться тут. По идее, можно утащить эти бинарники в свое приложение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9527831/3955135) на похожий вопрос на англоязычном SO, там же приведен пример кода.

Но это не совсем компиляция кода из строки. Нужно будет описывать структуру класса, а не использовать готовую строку.

Comment: Идея как раз в компиляции строки.

Comment: Тогда можно попробовать [другой вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28890356/3955135)

Comment: К сожалению, скорее всего, ничего не получится, поскольку там используются стандартные средства для компиляции jar, которые "вырезаны" в Android.

Comment: К сожалению, JVM андроида не позволяет компиляцию jar файлов равно как и компиляцию классов в runtime обычным образом. По этой причине, единственный вариант - использование dexmaker